# Why arguments moved twice when constructing std::thread

Tags: c++, c++11, move, stdthread

Consider this program that essentially creates `std::thread` that calls the function `func()` with `arg` as argument:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
   foo() = default;
   foo(const foo&) { std::cout << "copy ctor" << std::endl; }
   foo(foo&&) noexcept { std::cout << "move ctor" << std::endl; }
};

void func(foo){}

int main() {
   foo arg;
   std::thread th(func, arg);
   th.join();
}
```

My output is

```
copy ctor
move ctor
move ctor
```

As far as I understand `arg` is copied internally in the thread object and then passed to `func()` as an rvalue (moved). So, I expect **one copy construction** and **one move construction**.

Why is there a second move construction?

Comment: Bit related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50362849/why-move-constructor-is-called-twice-when-passing-temporaries-to-thread-function

Comment: Ah, a dupe in fact. Shame it can't be closed as such due to having no answers (because n.m. wrote their answer in the comments section for some reason)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass argument to `func` by value which should constitute the second move. Apparently `std::thread` stores it internally one more time before calling `func`, which AFAIK is absolutely legal in terms of the Standard.

Answer (score 1):

> So, I expect one copy construction and one move construction.

The standard doesn't actually say that. An implementation is allowed to do extra internal move constructions.

Doing so is potentially less efficient though. This was https://gcc.gnu.org/PR69724 and has been fixed for the upcoming GCC 10 release.