# In C++, How a std::thread can call a member function without creating an object?

Tags: c++, multithreading

If we have a class `H` with some `operator()` overloaded. How it is possible to create a thread from these member functions without instantiating an object from class `H`. Consider the following code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>

class H {
    public:
        void operator()(){
            printf("This is H(), I take no argument\n");
        }

        void operator()(int x){
            printf("This is H(), I received %d \n",x);
        }

};

int main(){

    int param = 0xD;

    //No object created
    std::thread td_1 = std::thread(H());
    std::thread td_2 = std::thread(H(),param);

    td_1.join();
    td_2.join();

    //From an object
    H h;
    std::thread td_3 = std::thread(h);
    std::thread td_4 = std::thread(h,param);

    td_3.join();
    td_4.join();

    return 0;
}
```

produce the output :

```sh
This is H(), I take no argument
This is H(), I received 13 
This is H(), I take no argument
This is H(), I received 13
```

The question is, how td_1 and td_2 called the member function `operator()` of class `H` without an object of class `H`?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with threading, to be able to call a member function either you need an instance of H, or the member function must be static. For passing objects (by reference) to threads have a look at lambda functions, and for starting threads have a look at std::async (IMO a better abstraction for starting asynchronous stuff)

Comment: `td_1` and `td_2` does create instances of the class `H`. You can confirm this by **adding a default constructor** `H(){std::cout<<"default constructor called"<<std::endl;}` inside your class.  [DEMO](https://onlinegdb.com/CAXX7BkYW)

Comment: In `std::thread(H())`, the `H()` is creating a temporary object.  it is that object that gets the `operator ()` called on.

Comment: @NathanOliver `std::thread` will make a copy of the temporary and `operator()` will be called on that copy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> how td_1 and td_2 called the member function operator() of class H without an object of class H?

`td_1` and `td_2` does create objects of type `H`. Those objects are temporaries. Next, those supplied **function object**(which are temporaries in this case) are moved/copied into the storage belonging to the newly created thread of execution and invoked from there.

You can confirm this by adding a **default  constructor** and **move constructor** inside class `H` as shown below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>

class H {
    public:
        void operator()(){
            printf("This is H(), I take no argument\n");
        }

        void operator()(int x){
            printf("This is H(), I received %d \n",x);
        }
        //default constructor
        H()
        {
            std::cout<<"default constructor called"<<std::endl;
        }
        //move constructor 
        H(H&&)
        {
            std::cout<<"move constructor called"<<std::endl;
        }

};

int main(){

    int param = 0xD;

    std::thread td_1 = std::thread(H());
    std::thread td_2 = std::thread(H(),param);

    td_1.join();
    td_2.join();

 
    return 0;
}
```

The [output](https://onlinegdb.com/ArP9JFkPl) of the above program is:

```
default constructor called
move constructor called
move constructor called
default constructor called
move constructor called
move constructor called
This is H(), I take no argument
This is H(), I received 13
```

Comment: Why move constructor is called twice? Can you tell me this question is related to which basic concept of C++? I just cant understand any answer here

Comment: A side question, How creating a thread like `std::thread t3(&H::operator(),H());` is also valid ? The `operator()` of `H` don't accept any argument

Comment: @Sadegg it's more about implementation of that constructor which is uses an overloaded version in that case. It takes a pointer to member and instance of object. If `ptr` is a pointer to a member function, and `obj` is an instance,  `obj.*ptr()` is the call to that member using `obj`.

Comment: @Sadegg For your other question take a look at [Why move constructor is called twice when passing temporaries to thread function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50362849/why-move-constructor-is-called-twice-when-passing-temporaries-to-thread-function). You can also ask a separate question for why move constructor called twice if the above provided link doesn't have any accepted answer for that question.

Comment: @Sadegg " I just cant understand any answer here" Then you should start reading about objects, ownership, move idioms and the basics about temporary objects.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this function:

```
void f() {
    printf("This is f(), I take no argument\n");    
}
```

A thread that calls the function is constructed like `std::thread(f)`. Code like `std::thread(f())` is invalid, because the parameter of `std::thread` must be [callable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable) (in this case, [a function object](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/FunctionObject)). If you call the function before passing it to the constructor, `std::thread` can no longer call it.

So you pass `f` to the constructor, and it later becomes `f()`, and the function is called.

Similar to passing the name of a function, you can pass an object to the constructor, and the thread later calls `operator()`. When you write `std::thread(H())`, you construct a temporary object. Because class `H` has `operator()`, this code is accepted.

In fact, `std::thread(H{})` is also accepted. This shows that the parentheses refer to the constructor `H::H()`, rather than `H::operator()`. You did not write a constructor for the class, but the compiler creates a default constructor.

You could also use this code to construct a temporary object with `H()` and immediately call `operator()`:

```
int main() {
    H()(); // Valid: H() is callable
    //f()(); // Invalid: f() is not callable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `H()` is creating a temporary object of type `H` in this context. The temporary object is passed to the `std::thread` constructor.

Now, if the thread were to call `operator()` on that temporary, that would be a problem, since the temporary will only live until the end of the line `std::thread td_1 = std::thread(H());` and the thread function may execute after that.

However, the thread doesn't actually use that temporary. Instead a new object of the (decayed) argument type is created for the thread, copied/moved from the temporary object you gave to the constructor. This `H` object lives until the thread exits and on this object `operator()` is called.

Comment: So the line `std::thread td_1 = std::thread(H());`, the `H()` is the constructor or the `()` operator of temp object of class `H` ?

Comment: @Sadegg The `H()` is for the constructor and not for overloaded `operator()`.